# VueJS recursive API call good practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

being pretty new to API development and web dev in general, i'm trying to understand what would be the best practice to make a recusive api call in my VueJS app.

Data :

Categorie

```
ID | ParentID |   Name
============================
1  |   NULL   |   Car
2  |   NULL   |   Bikes
3  |     1    |   Sports Car
4  |     2    |   Sport Bike
5  |     3    |   SuperBike
```

I'm calling an API to retrieve those cat and create a DropDown item starting by the those who have a NULL ParentID.

App.vue

```
<b-dropdown v-for="item in categories" :key="item.id" v-bind:text="item.name" id="ddown1" class="m-md-1">

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Top,
    Side,
    Center
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "USAFE",
      categories:[]
    }
  }, 


   created: function()
        {
            this.fetchItems();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchItems()
            {
              let uri = 'http://localhost:8180/unv-api/categorie/search/rsql?query=ParentId==NULL';

             this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                  this.categories = response.data._embedded.categories;
              });

            }
        }
};
```

Now I want to add sub Dropdown with child using the ParentId property.

What would be the best practice to achieve something like that?

Comment: You need to create a join with the parent table so you fetch the parent records straight away with a single call. No need to recursively make calls. If you fetch too many records at once by doing this, I suggest creating a limit with an offset so you can pagination your results.

Comment: The `b-dropdown` component is not a `select list` but an `action list`. Meaning that you **should not** treat it as a custom `<select>` component because it doesn't have a `v-model` property. Furthermore, you're creating a bunch of dropdowns from the items, not a single dropdown with multiple items.